# Differences between ROWTYPE, TYPE, and RECORD in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, rdbms, sqldatatypes

What is the use of the following declarations, and where will we use these types of declarations?

```
myrow tablename%ROWTYPE;
myfield tablename.columnname%TYPE;
arow RECORD;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [PostgreSQL's documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html):

- `TYPE` provides the data type of a variable or table column. You can use this to declare variables that will hold database values. For example, let's say you have a column named `user_id` in your `users` table. To declare a variable with the same data type as `users.user_id` you write: `user_id users.user_id%TYPE;`.
- `ROWTYPE`: A variable of a composite type is called a row variable (or row-type variable). Such a variable can hold a whole row of a `SELECT` or `FOR` query result, so long as that query's column set matches the declared type of the variable. The individual fields of the row value are accessed using the usual dot notation, for example `rowvar.field`.
- `RECORD`: Record variables are similar to row-type variables, but they have no predefined structure. They take on the actual row structure of the row they are assigned during a `SELECT` or `FOR` command. The substructure of a record variable can change each time it is assigned to. A consequence of this is that until a record variable is first assigned to, it has no substructure, and any attempt to access a field in it will draw a run-time error.

See the link for more in-depth examples.

Comment: It would be nice to know the performance advantages/disadvantages for each type. IOW, is a RECORD inherently less performant than using a ROWTYPE?